# Unable to get value using key in a map in thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

I am trying to get value by passing key to a map as shown below:

```
${userFieldValueMap.get(__${#strings.replace(field.sectionFieldName, ' ', '')}__)}"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
${userFieldValueMap[ __${#strings.replace(field.sectionFieldName,' ','')}__]}"
```